# SP2013: How to display item attachment (picture) in search web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, content-search-web-part

My goal is to build application similar to PivotViewer using search driven application.

I have list with elements and I want to display item's attachment (picture) as a tile in search result web part instead of item Title and Url. Is there any solution doesn't require writeing code?

Answer (score 1):

For a custom list, you will have to modify the items display template. Here is a good reference for that:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/04/understand-how-search-results-are-displayed-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx